# Spark REST Endpoint urls - Unable to access

Tags: rest, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a spark streaming job on yarn with spark diver in the cluster mode. I would like to access the REST endpoints as described in this [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/monitoring.html).

> Spark Version is 2.1

As per the documentation, the running application end points can be accessed at "http://localhost:4040/api/v1"

On the resource manager UI, clicked on the specific application and then Application Master tracking url to get the host name. Still it does not work.

> How do i find the node instead of localhost in the above url?

The other option given in the link above is using the base url "http://:18080/api/v1".

I tried the same by going through the RM as described above, but no success.

> How do i find the  for the above url?

Answer (score 2):

When you click "Application Master" link in Resource Manager UI the URL should be like "http://xxxxxxxx/proxy/application_121213133_1121212". You just need to add `/api/v1` at the end of this URL to access the API.

Comment: As per the spark documentations - "The endpoints are mounted at /api/v1. Eg., for the history server, they would typically be accessible at http://<server-url>:18080/api/v1, and for a running application, at http://localhost:4040/api/v1." Nevertheless, i tried what you mentioned but it still it does not work.

Comment: Edited the question with spark version

Comment: What do you see when you access `[APP_MASTER_URL]/api/v1`? 404 page or something else?

Comment: http://<IP>:8088/proxy/<app id>/api/v1  - The site cannot be reached in chrome.

http://<IP>:18088/api/v1/applications (as per docs) - This too gives the same result.

Comment: Are you sure that your Spark Web UI is visible at `http://<IP>:8088`? It's usually some random port, and this one doesn't look vary random :-). You can get the address when you enter Resource Manager UI, find an application and click "Application master" link. It should look like `https://some.host.here:9124/proxy/application_1510567277729_0004`

Comment: The application master url takes me tohttp://some.host.here:8088/proxy/application_...